# functions in pandas, filter to two dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, filter

I am learning functions in pandas and solving a problem. I have 2 dataframes. I need to attach to df by condition in a function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Nums':[ ['89' ,'1'], ['89'],['7', '23'],['7', '89', '13','11']], 'Ser': [88858, 54321, 88858, 98547]})
dfPP = pd.DataFrame({ 'Num':[ 5 ,89, 23, 13], 'SerPP': [12345, 54321, 88858, 98547]})
```

```
def rule(row,rowPP):
    if ((row['Nums'].isin(rowPP['Num'])) & (row['Ser'] == rowPP['SerPP'])).all():
         return rowPP['Num']
    else:
         return 0
```

```
df['New'] = df.apply(rule(df, dfPP), axis = 1)
```

Of course it doesn't work.
I am expecting a new column to be attached with the filter applied, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Nums':[ ['89' ,'1'], ['89'],['7', '23'],['7', '89', '13','11']], 'Ser': [88858, 54321, 88858, 98547], 'New':[ ['0'], ['89'],['23'],['13']]})
```

Comment: Side note, you should chose whether you want to use strings (`'89'`) or integers (`89`), don't mix both

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach is likely to use a list comprehension:

```
df['New'] = [[n] if str(n) in nums else [0]
             for nums, n in zip(df['Nums'],
                                dfPP.set_index('SerPP')['Num'])]
```

Output:

```
              Nums    Ser   New
0          [89, 1]  88858   [0]
1             [89]  54321  [89]
2          [7, 23]  88858  [23]
3  [7, 89, 13, 11]  98547  [13]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I learned more about list comprehension